# MVC5 how to find root path in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some helper methods to build Html output but it only comes out correct on my local dev and not my staging server. The ~ doesn't work since this is not Razor.

My local site path is http://localhost/testSite
My staging path is http://192.168.1.2/

On my local this produces 
    **src="/testSite/images.test.jpg"**
On my staging instance it produces **src="//images.test.jpg"**

```
var baseUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
var tb = new TagBuilder("img");
tb.MergeAttribute("title", "Main Image");
tb.MergeAttribute("src", baseUrl +"\images\test.jpg");
return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
```

I'm sure there is a method built in to do this on the code side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh... after reviewing all the helpers and context objects available, I must conclude there is no function or method that provides *exactly* what you want (other than to use the tilde in one of the functions, as shown in the other answers). All of them require some sort of string processing (e.g. `Split()` or `TrimEnd()`) in order to work.

Instead, Microsoft kindly gave us a band-aid function, [AppendTrailingSlash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.appendtrailingslash(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can use to solve the problem like this:

```
var baseUrl = VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);
var tb = new TagBuilder("img");
tb.MergeAttribute("title", "Main Image");
tb.MergeAttribute("src", baseUrl +"images/test.jpg");  //notice I removed the initial slash
return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
```

`AppendTrailingSlash` is guaranteed not to "double up" on the forward slash when the virtual directory is "/", so this should work for both your staging and development environments.

P.S. I'm pretty sure you should be using [AppDomainAppVirtualPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath(v=vs.110).aspx) and not `AppDomainAppPath`, which provides the physical path and not the virtual one.

Comment: This seems to return absolute path on disk not the base url of the site

Comment: Yeah I was just copying the OP's code. It should probably be `AppDomainAppVirtualPath` instead of `AppDomainAppPath`. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 1):

> var baseUrl = System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~/images/",
>   HttpContext.Current);

Using the GenerateContentUrl you can keep using ~/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try also with [Using double dot notation in URL link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186703/using-double-dot-notation-in-url-link)

**ex:**

../file would mean to look in the parent directory for file. If you had just file it would look in the current directory.

Thanks